# Are there proper $1/2$ convex subsets of finite groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, convex-analysis, abelian-groups

According to [this paper](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwiNjdWRuIzIAhUDxqYKHUb5Cbw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cdam.lse.ac.uk%2FReports%2FFiles%2Fcdam-2008-10.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGiSS7KNvhrxnlacCZC5jrLPqqgAQ&bvm=bv.103388427,d.dGY) by *N. H. Bingham* and *A. J. Ostaszewski*,

> A subset $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be $1/2$ convex (or mid-point convex)
>   if for each $x,y\in H$, there exist a unique element $z\in H$ satisfying the equation $z^2=xy$.

My questions are,

1. Can there be any $1/2$ convex **proper subsets** of finite groups? if not, why?
2. What are the other notions of convexity on finite groups ?

Comment: For 1., any cyclic group of odd order

Comment: A generalization of the definition that suggests itself would be: Any product of an $n$th power and an $m$th power is an $(n+m)$th power ... Specifically, such a group would be divisible ($1^{n-1}a=x^n$)

Comment: @frank000: Thank you for your response. But, I'm so sorry. I have to edit my question. What do you think about edited question. And I really appreciate if you can give a full answer.

Comment: If $K\le G$ is a subgroup of odd order, it seems to me that any coset of $K$ is $1/2$-convex. Just to show that a $1/2$-convex subset need not be a subgroup. Well, hardly suprising that a translation would preserve a notion of convexity :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you for your valuable comment. But considering cosets of $A_3$ in $S_3$ I see that not every coset of a $1/2$ convex set is not convex.

Comment: Nilan, the group $S_3$ is not abelian. I'm fairly sure I read somewhere in your question that you restricted to abelian groups. Can't see it now

Comment: Oh, in the tags!

Comment: Nice catch :) I will check your Idea on abelian groups. Also I will let you know, if I found something. Any way thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As frank000 points out, any cyclic group of odd order is $1/2$-convex. So if you have a non-cyclic $1/2$-convex group and take an element of odd order, the subgroup generated will be a proper $1/2$-convex subgroup. For an example, let $n$ be an odd positive integer and consider $\mathbb G=Z_n^2$. This is a $1/2$-convex group, and the subgroup $H$ generated by $(1,0)$ is also $1/2$-convex.

As Hagen von Eitzen suggested in the comments, a natural generalization would be: given positive integers $m$ and $n$, a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is $(m,n)$-convex if for all $x,y\in H$, there exists a unique $z\in H$ such that $x^my^n=z^{m+n}$ (so in this new terminology, $1/2$-convexity is the same as $(1,1)$-convexity). For example, $\mathbb Z_k$ is $(m,n)$-convex if and only if $k$ and $m+n$ are coprime. In particular, this shows there is no finite cyclic group $G$ which is $(m,n)$-coprime for all $m,n$.